# Reformat from datetime64[ns] to date[d]

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How do I change the dates in my plot to show just the day and not datetime64[ns]? I would like to remove the time (MM-DD-YYYY)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
import matplotlib.dates as mdates 
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

import json

with open('outputfile.json') as f:
data = json.load(f)

dates = [item['created_at'] for item in data['data']['prices']]
values = [item['price'] for item in data['data']['prices']]

df = pd.DataFrame(({'dates':dates, 'values':values}))
df['dates']  = [pd.to_datetime(i) for i in df['dates']]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90)
plt.plot(dates, values)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Price')
```

[clip of my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fzCp.png)

Comment: Take a look at [DateFormatter](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/61483/matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter).

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably looking for is the [`TimeStamp.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.strftime.html?highlight=strftime) method. It allows you to format the date object into a string with the format you choose. (The link to the documentation there is practically useless for some reason. More details are shown [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html))

This is a handy reference for all the types of symbols you can use to format the date how you want it: https://strftime.org/